# WYSIWYG Wordpress readme.txt file Markdown Viewer

Tags: wysiwyg, wordpress.org, readme

I'm ready to upload my first Wordpress Plugin and although I'm pretty sure I nailed the readme.txt file I thought it would be nice if I could preview it before uploading the zip file.  My search has come up empty for actual WYSISYG.

I was looking for a viewer that would show all tabs and embedded videos etc. exactly as they would appear in the Plugin Store.  I tried a couple of generators but they just did very basic formatting and I actually found it easier to just use notepad text editor.

Maybe I'm dreaming.  Is the standard procedure to do the best you can, upload the zip and then make any tweaks based on how the page looks in the plugin store?

Not that big of deal to do it that way but just wanted to ask first.

Thank for any help you can give me.

Answer (score 1):

The code used on wordpress.org to render `readme` files is here: [class Markdown](https://meta.svn.wordpress.org/sites/trunk/wordpress.org/public_html/wp-content/plugins/plugin-directory/class-markdown.php). You can download the class and the [dependencies](https://meta.svn.wordpress.org/sites/trunk/wordpress.org/public_html/wp-content/plugins/plugin-directory/libs/michelf-php-markdown-1.6.0/Michelf/), then you should be able to set up a simple custom reader. If you want to see it as close as possible to the actual page, you can download/checkout per SVN the theme [from the same place](https://meta.svn.wordpress.org/sites/trunk/wordpress.org/public_html/wp-content/themes/pub/wporg-plugins/).

Comment: This seems complicated to get it working.  Is this something I download from github and install on my web server an then write my own front end web page to paste the markdown in?

Comment: @LarryRobertson I think you have to fetch it per SVN, then add it to a local, normal WordPress installation.

Answer (score 0):

Try out the WordPress Readme Validator here: https://wordpress.org/plugins/about/validator/ . Simple to use, will show you a good representation of all of the elements in your readme.

Comment: This is the one I have been using but it is not WYSIWYG in that I can't see the tabs and embedded videos.